# Powershell Web with Proxy

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I am getting a proxy error with my script. "The remote server returned an error: (407) Proxy Authentication Required."

IE uses a script to configure it's connection (that's all the info I have).  I looked in there and tried some IPs/ports in my script, but none seemed to work. Is there some other way of using this IE connection script in PS?

```
$web_client = New-Object System.Net.WebClient;
$web_client.Headers.Add("user-agent", "PowerWeb");

$proxyAddr =  "http://172.16.192.34:9090" 
$proxy = new-object System.Net.WebProxy
$proxy.useDefaultCredentials = $true

$proxy.Address = $proxyAddr

$web_client.proxy = $proxy

$data = $web_client.DownloadData("http://stackoverflow.com")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PowerShell 3.0 you can use `Invoke-WebRequest`